# Tweak logging of standalone Neo4j server

Tags: docker, neo4j, log4j2

When running the Neo4j standalone community Docker, some logs are written to stdout and some to a file inside the container: *debug.log*.

I would like to be able to set log4j options, like log-level, appenders etc. The reasons are:

- I can't access the log files when running in e.g AWS ECS
- The debug logs are quite verbose
- log4j-properties are convenient to deploy and manage

**So the question is, how can I set a custom log4j properties for a Neo4j server that's running inside a container?**

It's not documented if it's even possible, but I have tried the usual things one starts to thing of. First adding a `log4j.xml` to the classpath but to no avail. Also I have tried setting `dbms.jvm.additional` to

- `-Dlog4j.configuration=<path_to_file>`
- `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=<path_to_file>`
- `-Dlog4j2.configurationFile==<path_to_file>`

I've verified that the Neo4j process has the correct jvm-arguments:

```
/usr/local/openjdk-11/bin/java -cp /var/lib/neo4j/plugins:/var/lib/neo4j/conf:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/*:/var/lib/neo4j/plugins/* 
-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch 
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields -XX:+DisableExplicitGC 
-XX:MaxInlineLevel=15 -XX:-UseBiasedLocking -Djdk.nio.maxCachedBufferSize=262144 
-Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 
-Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=stackdepth=256 
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+DebugNonSafepoints -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true 
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/var/lib/neo4j/conf/log4j.properties 
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:/var/lib/neo4j/conf/log4j.xml 
-Dlog4j2.configurationFile=file:/var/lib/neo4j/conf/log4j2.xml 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint 
--home-dir=/var/lib/neo4j --config-dir=/var/lib/neo4j/conf
```

I have verified that no lib-jars contains a log4j-properties that takes precedence.

And whatever I try, no changes are made to the way the server is logging. The same events are written to `/logs/debug.log`. No exceptions regarding bad log4j config or something like that.

I have created a small [project](https://github.com/RickardCardell/debug-neo4j-logging) for easier debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I would write out the files to stdout.

```
# forward logs to docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /logs/debug.log
```

So this is a 'docker' solution but handy and works also for other usecases.

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly what I asked for :)  I want log4j options, so that I can filter the events as well. Also, your solution doesn't fly for the image above since the user doesn't have write access to "/dev/stdout" 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410080/docker-sending-log-files-as-non-root-user-to-dev-stdout

tail -f send the logs to stdout, but would require a change in the start-script which is not so clean, and would also not filter any events the log4j style.

Comment: Please add your filtering needs to your question. I have not seen these needs.

Comment: I think I am quite clear that log4j-properties is the solution I want. That includes filtering, setting log-level, appenders etc. But I can try to clarify